# Am stuck in parsing Push Notifications

Tags: objective-c

I want to fetch value of description from the below response. In body few more key-value pairs are there. I have tried, unfortunately am failing to crack. My code is in Objective C.

And My code for Parsing as below

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:notification.request.content.userInfo options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"After Validation JSON VALUE IS : %@", jsonString);


NSData *BodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[[[notification.request.content.userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] objectForKey:@"body"] options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *BodyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:BodyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"After Validation JSON VALUE IS : %@", BodyString);
```

Here is my complete response. I want to fetch all the values from body section.

```
{  
"aps":{  
"alert":{  
  "title":"Your bill is ready from shop My Store",
  "body":"{\"shop_id\":\"16\",\"shop_name\":\"My Store\",\"description\":\"Thank you for Shopping\",\"notification_type\":\"bill\",\"shop_category\":\"entertainment\",\"bill_date\":\"2018-01-13\",\"bill_url\":\"dXBsb2FkLzRvcmVfMDExMzIwMTgtMTY0NjI5LnBkZg==\",\"approve\":1}"
},
"sound":"1"
},
"gcm.message_id":"0:1515842219916508%a1c76c71a1c76c71",
"gcm.notification.vibrate":"1"
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to decode this? Please add it to your question. This looks like JSON-in-JSON, so you will need to decode twice.

Comment: "{\"description\":\"Thank you for Shopping\"}" is simply string (key value of body)..i think you should edit your response and convert "description" to dictionary at server side, only in that case you can access description as key-value

Comment: @halfer i have edited my question Thank you.

Comment: @MAhipalSingh. Without editing response from server side we cont parse that value?

Comment: you can try split a string with componentsSeparatedByString (using ",") but that would not a good way.

Comment: @MAhipalSingh Thank you. let me try and get back to you...

Comment: @PavanpadmashaliBS, pls check my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your body string to json

```
    NSString*bodyKeyValue = @"{\"shop_id\":\"16\",\"shop_name\":\"My Store\",\"description\":\"Thank you for Shopping\",\"notification_type\":\"bill\",\"shop_category\":\"entertainment\",\"bill_date\":\"2018-01-13\",\"bill_url\":\"dXBsb2FkLzRvcmVfMDExMzIwMTgtMTY0NjI5LnBkZg==\",\"approve\":1}"; //[[[notification.request.content.userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] objectForKey:@"body"];

    NSData *data = [bodyKeyValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* jsonOutput = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonOutput);

    NSLog(@"approve Key value:%@",[jsonOutput objectForKey:@"approve"]);
```

Comment: Awesome @MAhipal Singh Code Working like a charm. I was working on your previous suggestion "componentsSeparatedByString (using ",")" and i almost did that but you saved my day by the above code. Thank you. +1. :)